# numpy array metadata change

Tags: python, numpy, metadata, stride

I know that numpy stores numbers in contiguous memory.  So is it possible to take

```
a = np.array([127,127,127,127,127,127,127,127], dtype=np.uint8)
```

the binary representation of 'a' is all ones

to this:

```
b = np.array([72057594037927935], dtype=np.uint64)
```

as well as back again from b->a.

The binary representation is all ones however the number of elements is combined to one single 64 bit int
the representation should be the same in Numpy only the metadata should change.

This sounds like a job for stride tricks but my best guess is:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(1,), strides=(8,8))
```

and

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b, shape=(8,), strides=(1,8))
```

only to get ValueError: mismatch in length of strides and shape

This only needs to be read only so I have no delusions thinking that I need to change the data.

Comment: @Divakar uint7 one bits, apparently :)

Comment: See also `a.tobytes()` which contains `\x7f` rather than `\xff` blocks.

Comment: Copyist mistake 0b1111111 (7 x1's *8) I was missing a leading zero to start with.  But there it is ...  I wonder if I will change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *reinterpret* the existing data in an array you need [`numpy.ndarray.view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy.ndarray.view). That's the main difference between `.astype` and `.view` (i.e. the former converts to a new type with the *values* being preserved, while the latter maintains the same memory and changes how it's interpreted):

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([127,127,127,127,127,127,127,127], dtype=np.uint8)
b = a.view(np.uint64) 
print(a) 
print(b) 
print(b.view(np.uint8))
```

This outputs

```
[127 127 127 127 127 127 127 127]
[9187201950435737471]
[127 127 127 127 127 127 127 127]
```

Note that `127` has a leading zero in its binary pattern, so it's *not* all ones, which is why the value we get in `b` is different from what you expect:

```
>>> bin(b[0])
'0b111111101111111011111110111111101111111011111110111111101111111'

>>> bin(72057594037927935)
'0b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
```

What you seem to assume is a set of `uint7` values of one bits...

Anyway, the best part about `.view` is that the exact same block of memory will be used unless you explicitly copy:

```
>>> b.base is a
True
```

The corollary, of course, is that mutating `b` will affect `a`:

```
>>> b += 3

>>> a
array([130, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127], dtype=uint8)
```

To control endianness you'd want to use [string-valued dtype specifications](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types), i.e. `a.view('<u8')` (little endian) or `a.view('>u8')` (big endian). We can use this to reproduce the faulty number in your question:

```
>>> a2 = np.array([0] + [255] * 7, dtype=np.uint8)
... a2.view('>u8')
array([72057594037927935], dtype=uint64)
```